# Unable to create new Postgres Table for Elixir's Phoenix

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm following https://robots.thoughtbot.com/testing-a-phoenix-elixir-json-api

And I'm attempting to create a migration.

When I run mix ecto.migrate I get:

```
/code/mpa:.mix ecto.migrate
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.141.0>, {:query, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"schema_migrations\" (\"version\" bigint PRIMARY KEY, \"inserted_at\" timestamp)", []}, :infinity)
    ** (EXIT) %Postgrex.Error{message: nil, postgres: %{code: :invalid_catalog_name, file: "postinit.c", line: "794", message: "database \"mpa_dev\" does not exist", pg_code: "3D000", routine: "InitPostgres", severity: "FATAL"}}
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:356: GenServer.call/3
    (postgrex) lib/postgrex/connection.ex:102: Postgrex.Connection.query/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex:31: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.query/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:228: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query/7
    (ecto) lib/ecto/pool.ex:159: Ecto.Pool.do_run/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:216: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query/6
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:191: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query/5
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1261: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
```

but I just created the table. Checking in Postgres:

```
~:.psql -d template1
psql (9.4.4)
Type "help" for help.

template1=# CREATE TABLE mpa_dev();
ERROR:  relation "mpa_dev" already exists
template1=#
```

why am I getting this error & how can I create the table?

Answer (score 1):

As it is clear from the error message:

> "database \"mpa_dev\" does not exist"

You need to create a database named "mpa_dev":

```
createdb mpa_dev
```

and run

```
mix ecto.migrate
```

If you want the database name to be template1 (as you mentioned in your example), edit the database name in `config/dev.exs` and run the `mix ecto.migrate` again.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is complaining that the *database* "mpa_dev" does not exist, and you are checking for the existence of *table* "mpa_dev" in the built in database template1.

My guess is you have created a table within the database template1 when you meant to create a separate database. If connected to template1, you would create a database using command:

```
CREATE DATABASE mpa_dev;
```

See: [CREATE DATABASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html) in the manual. You can also use the command line [createdb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createdb.html) command from the shell.

Also note that in general it is not a great idea to create tables in template1, because template1 is the default template used to create any new databases you create using CREATE DATABASE. Since you have created a table in template1, every new database you create will contain this table from now on. I would recommend dropping that table before you do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the other answers (provided by harmic and emaillenin) provide a way of creating the database. I just want to point out a 3rd option if you have permission you can do:

```
mix ecto.create
```

Which will also create the database. This has the benefit of working with any storage backend. http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/0.15.0/Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Create.html

Answer (score 0):

```
message: "database \"mpa_dev\" does not exist"
```

I guess the DB is not existing.

I would do:

```
mix ecto.create
mix ecto.migrate
```